# Why memoized items are not persisted in parent components?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, memo, react-memo

I have a list with a large amount of items inside. In order to improve rendering performance I decided to memoize single items. This is the code I used:

**Parent component**

```
const randomList = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  const randomInteger = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  randomList.push({ id: randomInteger, status: "" });
}

const List = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState(randomList);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
     const position = e.currentTarget.id;
     const newList = list.map((item, idx) =>
      `${idx}` === position ? { ...item, status: "red" } : item
     );
     setList(newList);
  };

  return (
     <div>
        {list.map(({ id, status }, idx) => {
           return <Item id={id} idx={idx} status={status} onClick={handleClick} />;
        })}
     </div>
  );
};
```

**Item component**

```
export const ChipTermStyled = styled(({ ...props }) => <Chip {...props} />)(
  ({ status = "" }) => {
    return {
      backgroundColor: status,
    };
  }
);

const Item = ({ id, idx, status, onClick }) => {
  console.log(`item-${idx}`);
  return (
    <ChipTermStyled
      id={`${idx}`}
      key={`${id}-${idx}`}
      label={`${id}-${idx}`}
      status={status}
      onClick={onClick}
    />
  );
};

const arePropsEqual = (prevProps, newProps) =>
  prevProps.id === newProps.id &&
  prevProps.idx === newProps.idx &&
  prevProps.status === newProps.status;

export default memo(Item, arePropsEqual);
```

This should render **Item** only when id, idx or status change. And it does the job. But! When I update the parent component list, it doesn't keep the state between item updates. See this:

[image]

I check the list **before** and **after** on the first click and they appear ok, but on the second click, the list lost all the previous item statuses.

Why can this be happening? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with how the state is being updated. For anyone that is facing this issue, instead of updating the state like this:

```
 const handleClick = (e) => {
    const position = e.currentTarget.id;
    const newList = list.map((item, idx) =>
     `${idx}` === position ? { ...item, status: "red" } : item
    );
    setList(newList);
 };
```

You have to update it in the previous value of the state:

```
 const handleClick = (e) => {
 const position = e.currentTarget.id;
 setList(prevList => 
    prevList.map((item, idx) =>
      ${`idx`} === position 
         ? { ...item, status: "red" } 
         : item
    ));
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is caused by a combination of the memoization, and the way you update the list.

The `handleClick` function is re-created on each render, and contains the updated list:

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
  const position = e.currentTarget.id;
  const newList = list.map((item, idx) =>
    `${idx}` === position ? { ...item, status: "red" } : item
  );
  setList(newList);
};
```

However, your memoization ignores changes to `handleClick`, and all your components, except the last updated hold a reference to stale version of `handleClick`, which contains the original version of the `list` in which nothing is marked:

```
const arePropsEqual = (prevProps, newProps) =>
  prevProps.id === newProps.id &&
  prevProps.idx === newProps.idx &&
  prevProps.status === newProps.status;

export default memo(Item, arePropsEqual);
```

To solve that problem, and still have memoization on the `Item` component, wrap `handleClick` with `useCallback`, and use a function to update the state instead of using `list` directly:

```
const handleClick = useCallback(e => {
  const position = e.currentTarget.id;
  setList(prevList => 
    prevList.map((item, idx) =>
      ${`idx`} === position 
        ? { ...item, status: "red" } 
        : item
  ));
}, []);
```

Now all the properties are memoized, and you don't need `arePropsEqual`  anymore, so just wrap your component with `memo` directly:

```
const Item = memo(({ id, idx, status, onClick }) => {
  const key = `${id}-${idx}`;
  
  return (
    <div
      id={idx}
      className="item"
      style={{ background: status }}
      onClick={onClick}
    >{key}</div>
  );
});
```

**Demo**:

```js
const { useState, useCallback, memo } = React;

const Item = memo(({ id, idx, status, onClick }) => {
  const key = `${id}-${idx}`;
  
  return (
    <div
      id={idx}
      className="item"
      style={{ background: status }}
      onClick={onClick}
    >{key}</div>
  );
});

const generateList = () => {
  const randomList = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    const randomInteger = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    randomList.push({ id: randomInteger, status: "" });
  }
  
  return randomList;
};

const List = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState(generateList);

  const handleClick = useCallback(e => {
     const position = e.currentTarget.id;
     setList(prevList => 
      prevList.map((item, idx) =>
        `${idx}` === position 
          ? { ...item, status: "red" } 
          : item
     ));
  }, []);

  return (
     <div>
        {list.map(({ id, status }, idx) => (
          <Item 
            key={`${id}-${idx}`}
            id={id} 
            idx={idx} 
            status={status} 
            onClick={handleClick} />
        ))}
     </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<List />);
```

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.25em;
  margin: 0.25em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 25%;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```